# protect/release files on webserver with PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, security

I have following problem.
Each user have his own folder on a webserver. In each folder are different Files (pdf's, txt, ...).

```
0815
|-test.pdf
|-test2.pdf
0816
|-test444.pdf
|test45455.pdf
...
```

After Login (username = folder-name) the user get a list of his files in his folder, and can download it.

But EVERYBODY can see all files from another user.

for example:

```
www.example.com/0815
```

will list all files from the user.

Can can I protect the files with a PHP-Login, or is there any way I can do this with .htaccess?

Very many thanks in advance, Patrick.

Comment: yes. there are lots of ways. so many, that it is impossible to answer this question in the scope of SO - it is just **too broad**

Comment: could you pls give me a example, or a link with a solution? :)

Comment: You could use htaccess in combination with htpsswd in each directory for a simple solution.

Comment: There are a lot of people asking variations on this problem. I gather somewhere someone is giving this as a test of some sort...

Comment: Hello, I didnt wanted to use htaccess and htpasswd, cause I want to make a Login Page in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess` file, this will prevent from listing the directory.

PS: Make sure you set [allowoverride options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) (for this virtual host) on your `httpd.conf` or the above won't work.

Comment: Although this would presumably prevent the user from accessing their own list of files. The problem would seem to be the OP's authentication model?

Comment: I agree with w3dk, you shouldn't have to concern about this with a proper authentication model, review it.